# Downloading a wav file using Horseman and PhantomJS losing data quality

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, phantomjs, base64

I'm using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [HorsemanJS](http://www.horsemanjs.org/) to download a wav file from a remote server. However when the file is base64 encoded and written to a new file it loses quality which makes it unusable. The audio is there but its distorted which leads me to think that its an encoding problem. I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 using node v5

Below is my script any ideas maybe to improve the base64 encoding?

```
var Horseman = require('node-horseman');
var horseman = new Horseman({cookiesFile:'./cookiejar'});
var fs = require('fs');

horseman.on("urlChanged", function(url){
  console.log(url);
});

horseman.on('consoleMessage', function( msg ){
  console.log(msg);
});

horseman
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
  .open('https://remoteserver.com/audo.aspx?guid=01439900-5361-4828-ad0e-945b56e9fe51')
  .waitForNextPage()
  .type('input[name="password"]', process.env.PASS)
  .type('input[name="username"]', process.env.UN)
  .click("button:contains('Login')")
  .waitForNextPage()
  .evaluate(function(){
    var base64EncodeChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    function base64encode(str) {
        var out, i, len;
        var c1, c2, c3;

        len = str.length;
        i = 0;
        out = "";
        while(i < len) {
        c1 = str.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
        if(i == len)
        {
            out += base64EncodeChars.charAt(c1 >> 2);
            out += base64EncodeChars.charAt((c1 & 0x3) << 4);
            out += "==";
            break;
        }
        c2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
        if(i == len)
        {
            out += base64EncodeChars.charAt(c1 >> 2);
            out += base64EncodeChars.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
            out += base64EncodeChars.charAt((c2 & 0xF) << 2);
            out += "=";
            break;
        }
        c3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
        out += base64EncodeChars.charAt(c1 >> 2);
        out += base64EncodeChars.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
        out += base64EncodeChars.charAt(((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >>6));
        out += base64EncodeChars.charAt(c3 & 0x3F);
        }
        return out;
    }

    var url = $("a:contains('Uncompressed file')").attr("href");

    console.log(url);

    var out;
    $.ajax({
      'async' : false,
      'url' : url,
      'success' : function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
        out = base64encode(data);
      }
    });
    return out;
  })
  .then(function(out){
    fs.writeFile('./mydownloadedfile.txt', out, 'base64', function(){
      return horseman.close();
    });
  });
```

The content-type comes back as `audio/wav`

If the file is manually downloaded and played via the same player it plays fine, it is only when it goes through this process.

Comment: This needs more information.  Specifically, can you download the file and save it?  It sounds like a codec pulling the wrong time sequencing, but a sample wav file is needed.

Comment: You could download a file with less code with CasperJS instead of PhantomJS and you wouldn't have to use the workaround through base64.

Comment: @st2erw2od I'll look into CasperJS but when I originally investigated it was standalone so I couldn't do what I needed after the fact with the file (store on S3)

Comment: @CharlesMerriam yes I can manually download the file and play it with the same audo player I'm using to play the file after it goes through this process. The original wav file when downloaded directly is perfect quality so its not a codec issue, unfortunately the information in the wav file (call recording) is sensitive data so I can't provide a public example

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check environment and use **Buffer** in NodeJS or **btoa()**/**atob()** in browser, for base64 encoding and decoding:

```
function base64Encode(plainData) {
    if(isNode) {
        return new Buffer(plainData).toString('base64');
    }else {
        return window.btoa(plainData);
    }
}

function base64Decode(encodedData) {
    if(isNode) {
        return new Buffer(encodedData, 'base64').toString();
    }else {
        return window.atob(encodedData);
    }
}
```

in your script:

```
var out;
$.ajax({
  'async' : false,
  'url' : url,
  'success' : function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(status);
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
    out = base64Encode(data);
  }
});
return out;
})...
```

Comment: Buffer is NodeJS only so can't be injected into the browser, the script where I'm base64 encoding and where the problem lies.

Comment: Yes, that's because in the question you said: "I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04 using node v5" and I assumed you need nodejs based solution. What about detecting environment (node|browser) and running appropriate methods, like Buffer in node and atob()/btoa() in browser? Updated my answer.